# Check and Return Keyword in a List of String

Tags: c#, string, search

I was wondering if there's a way to check if a string contains any of the keyword is a list, and return the found keyword if found.

For example, I have a list of `keywords`.

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>{"word1", "word2", "word3"};
```

And I have a `sentence` (string) I want to check against keywords:

```
string sentence = "something something something word2 something something";
```

Is there a way to search for the `keywords` in the `sentence` and return the found one? For example, return `word2`.

I know I can probably just use a forloop to loop through keywords, but since there will be at least 20 keyword in my actual program, I don't want to do so as it makes my code kinda messy.

My original idea is like this:

```
string SearchKeywords(List<string> keywords, string sentence){
    foreach (string word in keywords){
        if (sentence.Contains(word)) return word;
    }
    return ""; //return blank string if no match found
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a built-in function that I can use to do the job. Thanks!

Comment: there is no built in function. you could use Regex, which is what it really is used for. The problem you have in your original idea is, what if the sentence or the word is not the same case? it will fail

Comment: What if multiple words on your list are in your sentence?  Do you want those back, too?  And, as Ahmed mentioned- does casing matter (upper v lower)?

Comment: case doesn't matter, so I think I can simply add the ToLower() to solve the case problem. I'm trying to parse a Q&A document, so it's pretty safe to assume that one sentence will contain at most one keyword. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex, you can create an alternation using your keywords to get a pattern of `word1|word2|word3`. They should be escaped via `Regex.Escape` to avoid conflicting with any regex metacharacters. Ignoring case is done by adding the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option.

```
string pattern = String.Join("|", keywords.Select(k => Regex.Escape(k)));
Match m = Regex.Match(sentence, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Keyword found: {0}", m.Value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No keywords found!");
}
```

If you change your mind and want to find multiple matches, use `Regex.Matches` instead and loop through its results.

Comment: I like this solution, because the regex should mean that you're not searching through the string over and over - just one intelligent, easy search.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Linq's [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
string SearchKeywords(List<string> keywords, string sentence){
    return keywords.FirstOrDefault(w => sentence.Contains(w)) ?? "";
}
```

The `?? ""` at the end simply means that if no keyword is found within the string, your method should return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you'll only get one word per sentence (and you're sure you're only checking one sentence at a time), I'd use p.s.w.g's answer.  For a similar one which will look through a longer string (and thus possibly return multiple results) just use `.Where()` like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> SearchKeywords(List<string> keywords, string sentence)
{
  return keywords.Where(w => sentence.ToLower().Contains(w.ToLower()));
}
```

In this case, you don't need the `null` coalescing operator (`??`) because the Enumerable will be returned either way, if there aren't any matches, then it will return an Enumerable with no elements.

Note that this will find partial-word matches (for instance, keyword "cray" would match on sentence word "crayon."  You can fix that by adding spaces around your keywords (thus: " cray "), or by splitting your sentence into an array with `.Split()` and check the two Enumerables against each other:

```
IEnumerable<string> SearchKeywords(List<string> keywords, string sentence)
{
  var splitSentence = sentence.ToLower().Split(' ');
  return keywords.Intersect(splitSentence);
}
```